# Determine a transformation from a octahedron centered at $0$, of height and width $1$, to the unit cube centered at $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, euclidean-geometry

I have been working on this problem for a while, and I still do not have a clue as to how to approach this problem.  We can determine the points in the octahedron as those points $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ satisfying:
$\max\{|x|,|y|\} + |z| \leq \frac{1}{2}.$

Clearly, $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ is contained in the unit cube centered at $0$, if $\max\{|x|,|y|,|z|\} \leq 1/2$.  However, this doesn't necessarily lend itself to a relatively simple solution involving a radial, bi-Lipschitz map from the octahedron to the cube.

Any thoughts on how to approach this problem?

Comment: Does the map have to be explicit? You can just take the radial scaling homeomorphism between both the octahedron and the cube to the sphere (divide by the norm), and then compose.

Comment: I think it would be easier to map the points of the octohedron onto an inscribed inner cube. You can visualize where points should map to.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write the octahedron as $f(x,y,z) = |x|+|y|+|z|\le 1/2$.  The cube is 
$g(x,y,z) = \max(|x|,|y|,|z|) \le 1/2$.  You can try mapping
$$ (x,y,z) \mapsto \frac{f(x,y,z)}{g(x,y,z)} (x,y,z) $$

Comment: Shouldn't the ratio be between the points furthest from the origin in a given angular direction, so dependent on the spherical angles $\theta$ and $\phi$?

Comment: Yes, it is.  If you want to express it in spherical coordinates, you may.